# Solve for the word (2)

Tags: logical-deduction, word

The word:

---

Mercury

Mars + Earth + Uranus

Neptune + Jupiter + Mercury + Saturn

---

Hints:

> Q = 17              ,Arrangements

Comment: Using the order from the sun and then using A1Z26 I get AMT. Which doesn't see to be the answer...

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil you might wanna check again

Comment: @Beastly Add correctly Gerbil! Second line is 14, not 13.

Comment: @Sid nah arrangements is related to the planets

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the answer:

> Boringly, all we have to do is add up the positions of the planets from the sun and then use A1Z26. (**Note**- Beastly Gerbil has mentioned this in a comment. But, since I too came up independently with it and he doesn't seem to be answering it, I have gone ahead and posted my answer.)
>  First Row=1=A
>  Second Row=14=N
>  Third Row= 20=T

All of this work leads to the final answer of:

> **ANT**

Comment: Ah oops. Cost me an answer :) (I was away - sorry for not responding)

Comment: Well this is just a warm up wait for solve for the word (3) but why does it take 6 days to post another question :/

Comment: @Hyperactive maybe because your first question had a negative vote? I dunno. You can post on meta.